# Is spawning a process a good way to deal with a memory leak in python?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, python-multiprocessing

I have a python method which causes a memory leak when it executes, the leak itself originates in a C library with python bindings which I have no control over:

```
for i in range(10):
    do_some_c_stuff() # Memory leaks at every invocation, not freed by garbage collector
```

I found that if I spawn a process and then terminate it the memory is freed up:

```
for i in range(10):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_some_c_stuff)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    p.terminate() # Memory is freed up here, (by the OS?)
```

My question is - is this an OK way to deal with this problem or is there something better I can do?

Comment: Functionally it does sound like a good solution indeed (I assume you know why it works). The point to clear is the expected performance and/or frequency of the operation, since spawning a process isn't exactly a free and light lunch.

Comment: Thanks Pynchia, I have benchmarked the application with and without this process spawning trick and it appears to have the same performance - the function executes for a much longer time than the marginal cost of spawning a process. For now I will stick with this solution and eventually look into solving this problem at the C level.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is - is this an OK way to deal with this problem

I don't think so. Spawning a process is a costly operation, and doing that everytime you need to call that function could become very expensive.

> or is there something better I can do?

Yes: contacting the author of the software, and ask to fix it :)

If that's not possible I would start looking for an alternative. But using software, knowing it leaks, should be avoided at all times.